# How can open Firefox developer tools in my extension's sidebar?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have developed a Firefox extension which includes a sidebar using the SDK. However, if I right-click inside the sidebar and choose "Inspect Element", I get this error in my terminal:

```
JavaScript error: chrome://browser/content/nsContextMenu.js, line 570: TypeError: gBrowser is null
```

Needless to say, nothing happens and the developer tools do not appear.

I'm creating the sidebar using the SDK like this:

```
require("sdk/ui/sidebar").Sidebar({ /* etc */ });
```

Is there a way to open the dev tools for the sidebar?

Comment: So you want to open the sidebar from your sidebar? Or you want to open inside your sidebar?

Comment: @Noitidart: I don't mind where the developers tools pop up, I just want them to pop up so that I can debug my extension's sidebar.

Comment: Ah to debug chrome (not html) so like xul and stuff you can either use TriStrip Menu > Developer > Browser Toolbox then remote connect and inspect. Your other option is DOM Inspector and Element Inspector. After installing DOM Inspector, then Element Inspector, you can shift+right click anywhere and it will pop up with that thing you shift+clicked on. dom inspector: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/dom-inspector-6622/ element inspector: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/element-inspector/

Comment: @Noitidart: Hmm, those two extensions do allow me to inspect the DOM tree of my extension's sidebar, but I would like to use all of the dev tools. I don't know what "TriStrip" is.

Comment: The hamburger menu, the main menu.

Comment: This gets me me some of the dev tools: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Add-on_Debugger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just use the standard [Browser Toolbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Toolbox) and use the inspector to select the item in your sidebar that you want to work on. It's not as seamless as using the context menu but should get you what you need.

Once you've enabled it and opened it, you can click on this button [image] "Pick an element from the page", and then click on an element in your extension's sidebar.

Comment: In the WebExtensions world, this seems to no longer work: all you can select is an opaque `<browser id="webext-panels-browser" …></browser>` element. ☹

Comment: Yeah the question and answer is out of date now. You can do it in 2018-era Firefox from `about:debugging` - enable it, debug your addon and then use the iframe selector (top right for me) in the Inspector to pick your sidebar frame.

Comment: Hmm, it seems to be *kinda* working for me on Nightly with the Tree Style Tab addon. I can see what looks like the DOM of the sidebar, but it’s not actually that—it’s background.html rather than sidebar.html, and while modifications from the extension are reflected in the inspector, the other way round is not true, and most of the CSS rules seem to be missing as well, and the element picker isn’t operative. But this is not the place for such discussion; I might poke and prod more and maybe file a bug on Bugzilla. This is a very good start on what I needed, anyway. So thanks!

Comment: @ChrisMorgan, you need to select the `sidebar.html` frame in the iframe selector.

Comment: [Here is a tutorial about the `about:debugging`](https://www.reddit.com/r/FirefoxCSS/comments/a6tper/tutorial_inspectingdebugging_an_extension_sidebar/) ~